# Where does last 4 bytes of hmac go in wpa2 mic?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, wireless, hmac, wpa2-psk

The wpa2 mic is a 16 bytes array which is built by Hmac(sha1)
,But the Hmac(sha1) returns 20 bytes array.
So where does that 4 bytes go?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why can't HMAC-SHA1 return 16 bytes if you truncate?

Comment: Yes we can truncate it but I need all the bytes of the hash to decrypt it!

Comment: @msx forest is right, they actually get truncated.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be "negotiated" but the size of MIC is fixed to 16 octets, so independently from the algorithm used eventually it'll be truncated.

> **11.6.3 EAPOL-Key frame construction and processing**
>
> [...] EAPOL-Key frames are constructed and processed according to the AKM
>   negotiated at association time. **The negotiated AKM determines** what
>   algorithm is used to construct and verify a MIC, **the size of the
>   MIC**, and the algorithm used to wrap and unwrap the Key Data field.

**Table 11-9 - Integrity and key-wrap algorithms**
[image: Table 11-9 - Integrity and key-wrap algorithms]

So, they're discarded:

> **11.6.2 EAPOL-Key frames**
>
> HMAC-SHA1-128 is the EAPOL-Key MIC. HMAC is defined in IETF RFC 2104;
>   and SHA1, by FIPS PUB 180-3-2008. **The output of the HMAC-SHA1 shall
>   be truncated** to its 128 MSBs (octets 0–15 of the digest output by
>   HMAC-SHA1), i.e.,
>   **the last four octets generated shall be discarded**.

Taken from:

*Wireless LAN Medium Access Control (MAC) and Physical Layer (PHY)  Specifications. (IEEE Std 802.11 - 2012)*